# Should user and admin interfaces be separated in the code (separate classes) or should the not needed functionnalities be hidden through css

Tags: javascript, html, css, conceptual

Alright, so I'm pretty new to web development but I've gotten the hang of js/html/css and I'm working on a game/website. I am basically done with my work but I'm not sure about what I should do now

What I want to do is use the same admin interface I have with some restrictions to the user/player. For example, imagine an "admin" can add stuff to the website and move them around and such, while a player can only see and use them, while not being able to edit them or add new items to the view.

Also, I am using the same interface for many html pages and this is why I feel like I have to ask this.

**Should I clone the current classes and remove some the not needed stuff or should I just hide items with css and html?**

PS: The website is pretty big, there's a lot of classes which is why I'm hesitant.

I don't know if I should provide any code but an *example* of my question is :

**Cloning classes** - class "viewer" for admin and class "restrictedViewer" for player

**Hiding items** - just use "display: none" <-- This doesn't work on some items as they are only shown when some interactions happen, and I want said interactions to be available to player

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please take a minute or two to visit the Help Center to learn how questions should be asked_ so that you can get the best out of the website and hopefully some of the answers that you are looking for >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @maik I have looked through the help page, could you please explain what is wrong with my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really easy to overwrite some classes in the developers' tool, to access the admin functionality without having the proper rights. If security is of any concern to you, you should most definitely not hide the admin panels with a simple "display: none".

The way I would do it is to have a specific admin page, that can only be accessed if you have the correct credentials. However, that requires you to have a proper authorization system.

I understand that this solution is not really useful if you just want some extra buttons for admins. To prevent users from clicking something they shouldn't (because they messed about in the dev tools), you should also find a way to check the credentials upon clicking the button. In that case, even if the user somehow is able to display the button and clicks it, they can't really use it.

Another option is to have the buttons be generated by JS, and in that piece of code check the credentials to generate the buttons to match the user's role. This is a bit more tricky to "hack", as you cannot simply toggle a class or CSS property in the dev tool. Of course, you should still check the credentials in the button's handler anyway.

Just remember that hiding certain HTML elements is not a good way to secure them. You need to verify the user credentials on every step, including the handling.

Comment: I think I understand your solution, so I should definitely not just display: none my elements if security is a problem, and it will be eventually. 
I should be using a proper authorization system eventually, but not yet, and to be honest I don't really know how.

So for now, just duplicate the admin classes and basically cross-out (remove) everything I don't want? 
Most of my html is generated by JS anyway, the html files only contain basic outlines if you may.

About your last point, could you elaborate please? I don't know much about security, verifying on every step? 
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: With "on every step", I mean that you should verify if a user has the correct credentials on more than just one spot. If the button has a handler, verify the user is an admin in that handler before doing anything else. If the handler calls a method that does something important (such as saving something), you should check if the user is an admin in that method. If the handler goes to write something in a database using a backend call (which you don't have, I'm assuming, but still), you should check if the user is an admin in that backend call.

Comment: And yes, if security is a factor, you should implement a proper authorization system. Luckily, there are plenty of libraries available that handle the more complex stuff for you. Are you using pure JS, or are you using a framework like Angular/React/Vue.js? If so, finding a plugin to handle security is easier.

Comment: I understand @Stybar , so verification should be done often on the site. 
I will have a database to store all of my resources (photos, icons, etc.) but for now I'm doing everything locally (because that's how the project was started originally). Security will be a factor very soon, and I am to discuss this with other members here as there's already an authorization system implemented. 
For the record I am using JQuery only, the other libraries are 3D stuff like three.js

Comment: Both your answer and @slebetman's gave me more insight on the situation and helped me reach what I wanted. I wish I could choose 2 correct answers, but since I cannot I will choose Stybar's because I believe future viewers would prefer a more general view.
Thank you, both of you, for responding and for your time.

Answer (score 1):

For the UI either method is fine. All that matters is that admins get to access some pages that non-admins cannot see. Any mechanism you develop to achieve this is valid.

Now, there is another, very important part of web development that you haven't asked about: **authorization**. **For authorization, CSS is not enough**. You have to assume that users have and know how to use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or `curl` or Chrome/Edge/Safari/Firefox developer console. It's a valid assumption because these are common tools in web development and a lot (not a very big number but still a lot) of your users will likely be web developers.

You **must** make it impossible for non admins to call functions that only admins have access to.

There are several mechanisms to do this and most of the techniques that are considered best practices don't require you to duplicate classes. They generally involve a user role or permission mechanism.

The simplest implementation is a function that checks if the user has permission to access the page and you call that function as the first thing in your controller. Depending on your framework you can also use middlewares to do this since user role/permission/authorization is a cross-cutting concern. Some languages can make use of annotations/templates/macros to mark pages with permissions.

Whatever mechanism you implement, it must be done on the server because a user can always do:

```
curl http://your.website/some/admin/endpoint/to/restart/server
```

.. to access a page (or type it in directly in the browser). Sometimes you will need to implement some fancy validation or hiding in the front-end for smoother UI experience. That's OK. But that does not mean you do not need to also implement proper authorization mechanisms in the back-end.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer.
From what I understand, I should be adding attributes to my classes in that case to always check if the user is indeed an admin or not. And in that case another "init" function is called. In this init function though I will need to change or duplicate some of the original classes called because my functions do not separate all of the functionalities.
I will need to look more into security with the correct people at my workplace soon but I now know how to prepare everything to be implemented. 
Thank you

Comment: Basically yes. It depends on how you structure your application. You can use a combination of CSS and permissions - use CSS to show/hide special menu item/links then in the destination link use a permission mechanism to prevent unauthorized access. If you have a mixed page with some data that non-admins cannot have access to then you can use server-side templating to check permissions

Comment: But the types of structure of web apps is very wide and varied - even if we merely stick to the MVC design pattern. So the exact solution will depend on what you are using

Comment: I understand, I think I will have to think about user authorization more deeply and discuss this with the correct people, thank you though. I know there's a bunch of ways to do stuff on the web and it's not always easy for an amateur to choose the correct solution

Comment: Both your answer and @Stybar 's gave me more insight on the situation and helped me reach what I wanted. I wish I could choose 2 correct answers, but since I cannot I will choose Stybar's because I believe future viewers would prefer a more general view.
Thank you, both of you, for responding and for your time.